# Delete a branch from Remote

Tags: libgit2sharp

This is regarding API of libgit2sharp Remote Fixture.

I know how to Delete a branch from Remote using Push RefSpec. However, I wanna know how to do it using the API. I tried following example,

```
Repo.Network.Push(Repo.Network.Remotes["origin"], objectish: null, destinationSpec: branchName);
```

I provided correct `branchName` (checked remote). However, I get,

```
Unhandled exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'objectish')
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.ArgumentNotNull(Object argumentValue, String argumentName) in D:\git_ws\libgit2sharp\LibGit2Sharp\Core\Ensure.cs:line 24
   at LibGit2Sharp.Network.Push(Remote remote, String objectish, String destinationSpec) in D:\git_ws\libgit2sharp\LibGit2Sharp\Network.cs:line 273
```

related: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/466

How to properly call `Repo.Network.Push` to delete a branch from remote.

Out of curiosity I also tried the example from `RemoteFixture.cs` like this,

```
var remoteBranchName = "origin/" + branchName;
Repo.Branches.Remove(remoteBranchName, true);
```

This doesn't throw any error. However, it does nothing. Branch still exists on remote.

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the Push method that just takes push refspecs?

```
public virtual void Push(
            Remote remote,
            string pushRefSpec,
            PushOptions pushOptions)
```

The push refspec to delete references is described under the "Deleting references section here:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec

and would be similar to:

```
:refs/heads/branch-to-delete
```

Comment: Agree with @jamill. Just `:branch-to-delete` should work, too.

From a glance at the code, rejecting `objectish: null` is really unnecessary. Decade-ago me made a reasonable assumption.

Comment: @jamil Thanks for the reply. However, please note that I mentioned in the question description that I am able to do it using Refspec. I wanna know if it's possible do it in another way using `libgit2sharp` API.

Comment: The `Push(...)` method I referred to is part of the `LibGit2Sharp` API - would that version be suitable for you? (if not, why not?) It looks like the checks on the method you originally mentioned might be too restrictive, but modifying that would require a code change in the `LibGit2Sharp` library...